# Hot to use GraphServiceClient to access specific user resource not me?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing service application which sends mails from shared mailboxes. MS documentation specifies [how to get user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) but it gives only HTTP request sample. For signed-in user it specifies C# sample

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

I would like to use GraphServiceClient to access specific user

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GraphExplorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). It is a very useful tool. If you are logged in with your account, you can see the result.

Insert your URL and switch to Code snippets tab.

[image]

Comment: Related to GraphExplorer:
When I log on it uses my credentials. I would like to use credentials of ConfidentialClientApplication. I use Postman and HTTP request. This time I wanted to test GraphServiceClient